# Isn't dark matter just another fancy name and explanation for aether?

Tags: dark-matter, aether

I always get crucified by this, but it is something that has intrigued me for a lot of time, before Michelson Moorley and Einstein there was this idea that there was an invisible "substance" that permeated all of the universe, it was thought that this aether was used as a medium for EM waves, Maxwell believed in it, Faraday believed in it, Tesla believed in it, in fact a less known statement by Einstein was that he couldn't imagine a world without aether.

But today we basically believe that aether is a thing of the past, yet the first time I heard about dark matter was that it was something "invisible", that basically couldn't be detected, and that in fact most of the universe is permeated by this special type of dark or invisible matter, to me it sounds a lot like aether. Am I wrong to think of dark matter as aether, could dark matter be just a newer fancy word for what was considered aether? is aether dead or still alive? some people think aether is a very real thing.

Comment: Aether isn't a real material. Newton, in his corpuscular theory just used Aether as a theoretical term which fills space. The theory has been discarded now. Dark matter and Aether are not related at all.

Comment: 1) Dark matter can be detected gravitationally. The reason it is currently expected to exist is because introducing dark matter helps astronomical observations. 2) No serious scientist currently believes in the aether.

Comment: @d_b I understand, but let me say who says that aether can't be detected gravitationally? perhaps they couldn't back in the Michelson Moorley ages but now its possible

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_theories#Quantum_vacuum Read the quote by Robert B. Laughlin given here. The way it was defined before special relativity it doesn't exist. By redefining it we can consider quantum vacuum as Ether. But this terminology is not famous.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy yes that does seem to be very much like aether

Comment: Just because two things are supposed to be invisible, does that mean that they actually have to be the same thing? How about in the case where one of the two things has been definitely proved to not exist, and there are compelling reasons to think that the other one is real? Do they _still_ have to be the same thing?... Just because they're both invisible?

Answer (score 5):

The "aether" was postulated as a medium for the transmission of electromagnetic waves, which was experimentally shown to be unphysical.

Dark matter does not interact with electromagnetic fields or waves, and as such is a completely different thing altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The two concepts are unrelated. Dark matter is hypothetical matter that is detectable by its gravitational effects and explains galaxy formation and dynamics. Aether is a hypothetical material medium for electromagnetic waves that would be detectable but is found not to exist.

Answer (score 1):

All the Michelson Morley experiment showed was that aether was not [Lorentz covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance), so any aether in order to persist as a concept and be consistent with experiment would have to be Lorentz covariant, and be the carrier of electromagnetic waves. As dark matter is called dark because no light comes from it, it cannot be connected with electromagnetic waves.

A hand waving analogue to a Lorentz invariant aether for electromagnetic waves:

One can think that the photon field, postulated in the quantum electrodynamics field theory of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, the field permeating all space time, could be considered an aether for the electromagnetic field, on which creation and annihilation operators generate the photons which ultimately build up the classical field.